# How to embed all comments and comment form to other website

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, ajax, comments

I have two sites.one is Drupal site (example1.com). It has a lot of comments. I want to embed all these comments and comment form to other site (example2.com)[non-Drupal site].

Is it possible?

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: using drupal 7.

Comment: Well since you want to `embed` them, the only possible way would be using an `iframe`. You would have to create a view that contains your comments and add the comment box with php. Then you could modify your template files so the headers and footers of your site do not show up at that view page.

Comment: can you explain birefly.

Comment: Actually, @Robin is correct, using REST is the better/best way. Because with iframe you will end up with a scroll bar inside your iframe since you need to set a fixed height which will look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to expose the comments as a REST resource on example1.com. You can achieve this with the [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module (you will probably have to create a custom resource).

Then on example2.com execute a GET request on the REST resource and display the comments.

Edit: If you want to fetch the comments per node you will have to add a query param to the resource containing the node ID for which you want to fetch the comments.

Comment: can i submit comment from example2.com. if possible then how to put comment based on nodes. because i have 100 nodes. how to put comment for particular node.

Comment: I edited my answer. And yes it is possible to submit a comment on example2.com and save it on example1.com. You will have to add a POST request to your resource which then creates and saves a comment. Then on example2.com execute a POST request to example1.com